# Fastest and right way to check if I have a connection to SQL Server in C#

Tags: c#, sql, connection-string

I just want to check if I have a connection to a SQL Server for a sync my local database to it. And if I don't have to skip on it.

Also, it should work with wifi and cable connection.

When it connects with wifi some time my network is off but the method

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()
```

returns true so this method does not work well for me.

I also try just to check the connection to my SQL Server like that

```
public bool TestServerConnection()
{
     using (SqlConnection openCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
     {
          try 
          { 
              string saveStaff = "select 1";

              SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(saveStaff, openCon);
              command.CommandTimeout = 1;

              openCon.Open();

              if (openCon.State == ConnectionState.Open)
              {
                  return true;
              }
              else
              {
                  return false;
              }
          }
          catch (Exception)
          {
              return false;
          }
      }
  }
```

With this connection string

```
Data Source=CV-TED-SQL1;Initial Catalog = PulserDb; Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
```

But when I have no connection for example when I change `Data Source=CV-TED-SQL1;` to `Data Source=CV-TED-SQL11;`, the `openCon.Open();` takes about 10 seconds..

That just too long..

There is any fastest way to do that?

I can't change my connection string, maybe I can change it only for my method and change it back when this method end

Thanks for the help.

EDITING A NEW TEST METHOD

```
public bool TestServerConnection()
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            string tempCS = connectionString;
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder scb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(tempCS);
            scb.ConnectTimeout = 1;
            using (SqlConnection openCon = new SqlConnection(scb.ToString()))
            {
                try { 
                    string saveStaff = "select 1";
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(saveStaff, openCon)
                    {
                        CommandTimeout = 1
                    };
                    openCon.Open();
                    if (openCon.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        stopwatch.Stop();
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        stopwatch.Stop();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    stopwatch.Stop();
                    return false;
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: make sure your closing the connection as well.

Comment: But If I don't have a ConnectionTimeout on my connection string?
There is any safe way to split my connection string?

Comment: But It is a read-only prop

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: You are correct. It is readonly, but there is a workaround. Using SqlConnectionStringBuilder.

Comment: Just thinking a loud, open both connections at start of application and while executing query first check connection status (instead of making connection and executing query to find out availability) like if ( openCon.State != ConnectionState.Open) , if you find it closed then use the other temp connection. If in case you find both connection down then establish connection again.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change the connection string to add a Connect Timeout key then you can change the connection string at runtime with little effort using the SqlConnectionStringBuilder as shown below

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder scb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
scb.ConnectTimeout = 5;  // 5 seconds wait 0 = Infinite (better avoid)
connectionString = scb.ToString();

Console.WriteLine(connectionString);

using(SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
{

}
```

Comment: Also after changing like How I did In my edit of question
It takes about 5 secounds..

Comment: Where did you get that measure? There is no reading for ElapsedMilliseconds in your code above. Tried code like yours locally and I get 4 millisecs for a response but there is also the overhead of the exception handler